# Portlet overridden method does not thrown exception

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I am working on an example portlet that is supposed to show me users logged in when logged into luminus portal as admin and students logged in only see themselves and keep running into errors in my code so I am not sure how to fix these issues

This is the portlet code I am getting `overridden method does not thrown exception` when I added the `PersonException`

```
package com.test;

import javax.portlet.GenericPortlet;
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcher;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import com.sghe.luminis.person.entity.Person;
import com.sghe.luminis.person.exception.PersonException;
import com.sghe.luminis.person.services.PersonService;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 * WebApplication6 Portlet Class
 * 
 *  
 */
public class WebApplication6 extends GenericPortlet   {


    public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {

    }



   private static final Log cLog = LogFactory.getLog( WebApplication6.class );



    public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException, PersonException   {
        PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/WebApplication6_view.jsp");
        dispatcher.include(request, response); 



             response.setContentType("text/html");  
             PersonService personService = PersonServiceFactory.instance().getPersonService();
             List<Person> persons = personService.fetchPagedPersons( "givenname", "", 10, "1" );
             cLog.debug( "We have " + persons.size() + " people." ); 


   }
}
```

This is the `/WEB-INF/jsp/WebApplication6_view.jsp` code I was given as an example to work with

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "=//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<%PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();%> 
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.sghe.luminis.person.entity.Person" %>
<%
    List<Person> persons = (List<Person>)renderRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("PERSON_LIST");
%>            

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http=equiv="Content=Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <title>JSP Page</title>

    </head>


    <body>
        <h1>Person List</h1>
        <table class="summit2" border="1 padding="2px">
            <theader>
                <th>Display Name</th>
                <th>Login Id</th>
                <th>Person Id</th>
           </theader>
        <% for (Person person: persons) {%>
            <tr>
                <td><%= person.getDisplayName() %></td>
                <td><%= person.getLoginId() %></td>
                <td><%= person.getPersonId() %></td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
</table>


    </body>    


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Paul is definitely correct about overriding and exceptions, I think the design of your solution could use some improvement.

Why would you want to throw that exception up to the user in the first place? I would suggest handling that exception in a more controlled manner in your code and then displaying a user-friendly error message. If you just let the exception throw all the way to the top it's going to look very ugly and make your application look unstable and unpolished.

Comment: I may just be more confused on how i should handle this exception

Comment: Just don't throw the exception out of your portlet. Use a try-catch block to detech when the error happens then display an appropriate error message. If you let the exception throw out of your doView then you're letting LifeRay display whatever error message it chooses which may be useless to users.

Comment: OK , well i now deploy my portlet any nothing works no user data like it is supposed to have from the example i was given to follow from

Answer (score 0):

According to the [*Java Langauge Specification*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/), to override a method of a class ([8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)):

> More precisely, suppose that B is a class or interface, and A is a superclass or superinterface of B, and a method declaration `n` in B overrides or hides a method declaration `m` in A. Then:
>
> - **If `n` has a `throws` clause that mentions any checked exception types, then `m` must have a `throws` clause, or a compile-time error occurs**.
> - **For every checked exception type listed in the `throws` clause of `n`, that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the erasure of the `throws` clause of `m`; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs**.
> - If the unerased `throws` clause of `m` does not contain a supertype of each exception type in the `throws` clause of `n`, a compile-time unchecked warning occurs.

You could use an unchecked exception:

```
public class PersonException extends RuntimeException { ... }

public class WebApplication6 extends GenericPortlet   {

    public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) 
         throws PortletException, IOException, PersonException  {
       ...
    }

}
```